# Full HD resolution support

Tags: resolution

whether virtual nodes support full HD resolution, what changes is needed to enable FHD resolution for virtual nodes

Comment: Please clarify your definition of virtual nodes and add infos about the used hardware and operating system.

Comment: i want to create one v4l2loopback virtual node and want to get full HD resolution frames from both video0 node and virtual node (V4l2Loopback virtual node), i am using ubuntu 20.04

Comment: What have you tried so far, what research have you done, which commands have you ran? What is the specific problem you are facing?